# gwidgets2: how to prevent gbutton handler to run when change gbutton value?

Tags: r, handler, gwidgets

How can I change gbutton text without run the function associated to its handler?

Consider the following code:

```
library(gWidgets2)
w <- gwindow("Buttons", visible=FALSE)
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)

b2 <- gbutton("ouvrir", cont=g)

## with a handler
b4 <- gbutton("click me", 
              handler=function(h,...) {
                if(svalue(b2) == "open")
                  svalue(b2) <- "ouvrir"
                else
                  svalue(b2) <- "open"
                }, 
              action = NULL, cont=g)

visible(w) <- TRUE

svalue(b4) <- "Please not call the handler!!"
```

In gWidgets2 when I change the text of a button through the svalue() command, the button handler is called! However, I would like to call the handler just when the button is clicked. Any suggestion to solve this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code calls `invoke_change_handler()` when setting the label. There are a few ways to work around this:

- Block handlers before setting (`blockHandlers`) then unblock (`unblockHandlers`)
- Ir you could grab the underlying widget and set the text, in RGtk2 with gWidgets2 something like `obj$widget$setText("new value")` should work.

Comment: This solve my issue of multiple execution of functions called by clicking a button (explained on GitHub: https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2/issues/93 )